Angular problem on Win 11 Pro with docker desktop 4.30
I have a source code consisting of several docker containers (backend nodejs, frontend angular 10, etc) that is working just fine on win 10 with older Docker 3.24. Once i migrated to new PC with win 11 pro, wsl 2 and docker desktop 4.30 I can not compile the same frontend code. I keep getting 'ERROR in angular packages router router cannot be used as an entry component'. The containers are built on node:14.15.1-alpine image.
Not familiar with angular very much.
Any ideas? Thank you,
restart and reconfigure docker desktop
